# Search with multiple columns in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While using the command:

```
@items = Item.find(:all,:order => 'name', :conditions => ["name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:key]}%"])
```

This works perfectly fine, but the search is only based on just a column. How do i make it search other columns, like description, category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Rails 2, since you are using ActiveRecord 2 style syntax. You can just add the other columns as additional conditions, like this:

```
key = "%#{params[:key]}%"
@items = Item.find(:all, :conditions => [
  'name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR category LIKE ?',
   key, key, key
], :order => 'name')
```

For reference, here's how you would do it in Rails 3:

```
key = "%#{params[:key]}%"
@items = Item.where('name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR category LIKE ?', key, key, key).order(:name)
```

Comment: MetaWhere has been succeeded by Squeel (same author) http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/

Answer (score 1):

What if you have 15 columns to search then you will repeat key 15 times. Instead of repeating key 15 times in query you can write like this:

```
key = "%#{params[:key]}%"
@items = Item.where('name LIKE :search OR description LIKE :search OR category LIKE :search', search: key).order(:name)
```

It will give you same result.

Thanks